# Is it possible to set variables equal to expressions in UNIX?

Tags: unix, shell, variables, sh

In Unix, how would one do this?

```
#!/bin/sh
x=echo "Hello" | grep '^[A-Z]'
```

I want `x` to take the value `"Hello"`, but this script does not seem to work. What would be the proper way of spelling something like the above out?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`command substitution`](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/commandsub.html#COMMANDSUBREF) as:

```
x=$(echo "Hello" | grep '^[A-Z]')
```

You could also use the *outdated* back-quote style as:

```
x=`echo "Hello" | grep '^[A-Z]'`
```

Comment: +1 for that. I hate backticks with a vengeance since they're not nestable.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use shell internals without calling external tools, eg case/esac

```
str="Hello"
case "$str" in
 [A-Z]* ) x=$str;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

be sure that you are using expected regex supporting `grep`, grep has many variants across unixs.